# Attempting to ask a question on Area 51 Meta changes my profile picture

Tags: bug, status-declined, area-51, profile-picture

Every time I click the "Ask Question" button on [Area 51 Meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), it changes any profile picture I have to a default gravatar. Further clicks of the "Ask Question" button just generate a different default gravatar.

Note that it only changes the profile picture for Area 51 meta and leaves pictures as-is on all other sites.

Gif added - Ask Question each time opened in new tab, then closed. Rinse & repeat 4 or 5 times.

[image]

Comment: Odd… but true. gif added for simplicity.

Comment: Interesting additional oddness. If you open one of the questions, your gravatar is the last one generated by Ask Question, which then stays the same until you hit Ask Question again.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the gif - I couldn't get a gif version of the screen capture that wasn't grainy or horribly out of focus

Comment: And the edit link seems to be broken on profiles...

Comment: @lyxal - no worries:) For info, I use the Mac's built-in screen capture, then throw it at Gif Brewery to gif-ify it. You could probably edit out the google drive link now - it would break anyway once you removed it sometime later. The gif will live forever.

Comment: @Tetsujin gotcha. I removed the video link (it can still be found in the revision history though)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no edit for meta sites, on the regular sites it just redirects to the main site.

Comment: There's always been a bit of a mismatch between Area 51 profiles and Area 51 discussion profiles... I have to log in on A51 separately from Discussions (never the case for meta sites otherwise) and my avatar is different on the two sites - though both are gravatars instead of my custom one. Updating my profile content on A51 doesn't update Discussions profile content. Maybe updating profile on another site network-wide might? Haven't tested that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve updated the status to declined. This issue isn’t impeding community members from participating in Area 51 so it’s not a priority. I know this isn't an ideal state but wanted to be transparent that this fix isn't being prioritized.

Comment: Perhaps this should be `status-deferred` then.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat nah, they reject most if not all of the non-critical Area 51 bugs, so this is consistent. Better not give false hope, IMO.

Comment: This is a "won't fix" type of declined, @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @JNat Then I'm a bit confused about the difference. I thought "deferred" means "we agree it's a bug, but don't have time", while "declined" is "we think it's not a bug".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's not true. Per the extended tag wiki of [tag:status-declined], the tag *can also come up if the bug report is determined to be valid (i.e., not [tag:status-bydesign]), but the team has decided not to fix the bug for technical or performance reasons*

Comment: In addition to what Sonic said, "deferred" also means "it's in our backlog, and we _may_ get to it at some point," @HolyBlackCat — and that is not the case here.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Fair enough, but doesn't apply in this case. Those are not "technical or performance reasons".

Comment: @JNat This answer says *"not a priority at the moment"*, which implies to me that it could be fixed at some point later. But I'm not a native speaker, so maybe this is a roundabout way of saying "we'll never fix this". Also I'm sorry for nitpicking over this.

Comment: I'm re-reading the tag description, @HolyBlackCat, and don't see how it wouldn't apply here. It says: "Indicates that the feature request will not be implemented or the bug will not be fixed as a result of this question." That's as straightforward as it gets; but the tag description also goes into detail about this not being a "forever" type of "won't fix" and that we welcome re-asking if circumstances change, etc. What it is meant to convey here is simply: this will not be fixed; it will not be added to our backlog.

Comment: @JNat The tag matches what you're saying ("this will not be fixed"), I'm not arguing with that. But the answer says something else: "not a priority at the moment" (which to me implies "we may fix this sometime later"), rather than "we will not fix this". That's what I was nitpicking about.